# get the content of the prev element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure into my html.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Address</th><th>Option</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>here is the name</td>
        <td>here is the age</td>
        <td>here is the address</td>
        <td><button class="update">update</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>here is the name2</td>
        <td>here is the age2</td>
        <td>here is the address2</td>
        <td><button class="update">update2</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see from the above structure, the display will be this.

```
table header = Name, Age, Address, Option.
table body = here is the name, here is the age, here is the address, button update
table body = here is the name2, here is the age2, here is the address2, button update2
```

now what Im trying to do is when I click the update button, i must able get the content of the address td to name td at the single same row and each must be stored in a specified variable e.g. ($name, $age, $address). assume i have mutiple row, I must able to retrieve only the content of address td to name td of the same row. To be more precise, as the structure above, I must able to get the 'here is the name', 'here is the age', 'here is the address' and put each in a specified variable e.g. ($name, $age, $address) when I click the u"update" button and not the "update2" button.

so far what I tried is.

```
$('.update').click(function(){
   $address = $(this).prev('td').content();

   alert ($dateposted);

});
```

but seems not returning anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `content()`, or [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/6), because only the latter is a valid jQuery method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do it. After you get all the previous divs then loop them to set the value to the correct variable.

```
$('.update').click(function () {
    var contents = $(this).parent().prevAll('td');
    var name;
    var age;
    var address;

    for(i = 0; i<contents.length; i++){
        var currentContent = $(contents[i]);
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                name = currentContent.text();
                break;
            case 1:
                age = currentContent.text();
                break;
            case 2:
                address = currentContent.text();
                break;
        }
    }
    console.log(address, age, name);

});
```

For working example, please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/72j1oaqb/4/

Hope this help :)

Comment: how to access those variables e.g. name, age and address. for example if im going to alert the variable $name content. how im going to do that?

Comment: thank you. I found your way more precise. this cater my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here `this` is the button, which does not have a previous sibling, the `td` you are looking for is the previous sibling of the `td` parent of the clicked button, also you have to use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text)/[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) to get the contents

```
$address = $(this).parent().prev('td').text();//$(this).closest('td')
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. how im going to get the next td next to the address? i want to get the age and store it in $age. same goes with the name also.

Comment: If you need to get several values, it's more handy to add classes to your TDs and use something like `$address = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.addess').text();` and so on... Otherwise you're up for a `.prev().prev().prev()` nightmare which is unreliable if you change the HTML structure later.

Comment: thank you. i figured it out. all i have to do next is to add .prev to the first implemented prev call and goes for the rest.

Comment: Which is a bad idea if one day the age comes before the name.

Comment: you got a point. i must filter it then by adding classes so that i can make sure that i retrieve the exact content.